# Typescript: how to downgrade or ignore certain types of errors

Tags: typescript, compilation, warnings

It seems wrong that Typescript compilation fails with non-critical errors, although the strict code analysis is very helpful.

eg `Consecutive blank lines are forbidden`, or with unused variables/definitions when in development. Particularly the first one, since they are being compiled out.

Is there a way of downgrading or removing error messages based on type? I know we can....

```
// @ts-ignore
```

... for individual errors, but I am looking for a broader brush.

Comment: That sounds like tslint, and there should be a tslint config file where you can set rules

Comment: The "consecutive blank lines" error is a tslint error, and "unused variables" can come from either tslint or the compiler itself. Can you clarify which kind (tslint or compiler) you're trying to silence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `Consecutive blank lines are forbidden` is coming from the linter.  It can be disabled in `tslint.json` with the following configurtion ([TSLint core rules](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/)):

```
"no-consecutive-blank-lines": false,
"no-unused-variable": false
```

Each rule can also be associated with an object containing severity: `"default" | "error" | "warning" | "off"` ([Configuring TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration/)).  So you could use the following to downgrade to warnings:

```
"no-consecutive-blank-lines": { "severity": "warning" },
"no-unused-variable": { "severity": "warning" }
```

No unused variables/definitions may also have to be disabled in `tsconfig.json` ([TypeScript compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)):

```
"noUnusedLocals": false
```

I would like to note tslint has options to autofix the errors like consecutive blank lines using the `--fix` flag.  VS Code for example has an option to autofix linting errors on save, with this enabled the linter is a lot less of a hindrance during dev.

Comment: Your tslint snippet has the setting enabled (I think you meant to set it to `false`?). I'd also note that tslint has a `no-unused-variable` setting which OP may also want to disable.

Comment: Thanks @pariesz, that was the answer for removing those errors - I assume that there isn't an option to downgrade errors to warnings?

Comment: I have added the instructions to downgrade to warning.